# How do I get the error message from BadRequestErrorMessageResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Well, the question is simple as you might seen. I need to get the error message from IHttpActionResult method, which returns BadRequest. See the example:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SomeMethod(string data) {
  if (data==null) return BadRequest("Error messsage for you");
}
string data;
var result = await SomeMethod(data = null);
if (result is BadRequestErrorMessageResult) string error = result.ErrorMessageINeeded;
```

So, how do I get this one? Is there a class, which receives `result` object as a parameter and gets the error message from him? any ideas?

For somehow Message property is unavailable in `result`
[image]

Comment: [The Docs say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.badrequesterrormessageresult?view=aspnetcore-2.1) there is a `Message` property.

Comment: @Crowcoder thanks for reply! Yes, I read this docs and tried to access this property, but its unavailable

Comment: I'm not convinced your code is as shown given the screenshot of intellisense on `result`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        if (result is BadRequestErrorMessageResult errorResult)
        {
            string error = errorResult.Message;
        }
```

or, for C# versions older then 7.0:

```
        if (result is BadRequestErrorMessageResult)
        {
            string error = ((BadRequestErrorMessageResult)result).Message;
        }
```

Comment: Really confused now. That doesn't even compile yet it works?

Comment: @Crowcoder, okay, i lied to myself and to others. I didn't compile it yet I read your comment and yes, build is unsuccessful now

Comment: @Crowcoder, this code uses a new possibility intended in C# 7.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is. In older versions you need to use a habitual approach. I edited the answer to clarify this.

Comment: @Miamy gotcha. Thanks!